# The annual Stack Overflow survey

Tags: support, badges

I am trying to earn badges. How do I complete the stack Overflow survey?

Comment: The developer surveys are generally conducted in the month of Jan-Feb.

Comment: Please ask such questions in the [meta stackoverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: @ParsaMousavi There's nothing wrong in asking on [meta] as well. [Census badge](https://askubuntu.com/help/badges/294/census) is awarded on [ubuntu.se] too for answering SO's survey.

Comment: @AaronStone I can't do anything in this regard. The next survey will be conducted in Jan 2021. And that is decided by *the company*.

Comment: @AaronStone If you love badges, don't forget, Meta has its own set of badges separate from the main site, so you can collect them here too, just check your profile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just missed it this year, here are [the results](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/05/27/2020-stack-overflow-developer-survey-results/).

The only thing I can do to help you here is to point you to the SO [email settings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/current) and advise you to check the box for research. This way you should get an email for the next one.

Answer (score 3):

Stack Overflow's Developer survey is generally conducted every year in the month of January-February and results are announced somewhere between April and May. As [Mark Kirby stated](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/19171/816190), *you just missed it this year*.

Whenever a new is available, you'll see survey's announcement in the yellow box on the right side under *"The Overflow Blog"*. Currently, these are the *hot* topics on *"The Overflow Blog"*.

[image]

Alternatively, you can keep on eye on [survey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/survey?tab=Newest) questions on Stack Overflow Meta or [The Overflow Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/) or change email settings as noted by Mark. But again, *the company* would decide when the surveys would happen.

If you're eager to earn more and more badges, please visit [badges page](https://askubuntu.com/help/badges) in help center to know *the secrets* to earn them quickly. Also, please note, the badges are non-transferrable, i.e., Ask Ubuntu's badge won't be reflected on other sites on Stack Exchange network such as Stack Overflow or Super User. Meta badges are also independent of the badges on the main site.